# % not accepted as part of the string parameter in Web API

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, http-get

I want to send a string parameter to my Web API Endpoint. The string is: `TCmBqAKPGVMlTQ2Exw/viQ==`, so as we see it contains a `/`. I am encoding this string and now the value is `TCmBqAKPGVMlTQ2Exw%2FviQ%3D%3D`, but I still can not reach the API Endpoint.

This is the error I am getting:

> ```
> headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
> message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:31676/api/TokenTest/check-token-validation/96/TCmBqAKPGVMlTQ2Exw%2FviQ%3D%3D:
> ```
>
> 404 Not Found"
>       name: "HttpErrorResponse"
>       ok: false
>       status: 404
>       statusText: "Not Found"
>       url: "http://localhost:31676/api/TokenTest/check-token-validation/96/TCmBqAKPGVMlTQ2Exw%2FviQ%3D%3D"
>       **proto**: HttpResponseBase

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#attribute-routing) , you can try below code sample :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TokenTestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("check-token-validation/{id}")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> CheckTokenValidation(int id, string para)
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

If the request is `https://localhost:xxxx/api/TokenTest/check-token-validation/96?para=TCmBqAKPGVMlTQ2Exw/viQ==` you will get the correct result :

[image]

But url encode is always suggested .

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `encodeURIComponent(yourstring)` to encode special character in URL.

And change Url to `http://localhost:31676/api/TokenTest/check-token-validation/96?parameterName=TCmBqAKPGVMlTQ2Exw%2FviQ%3D%3D`